# Run merge-jsons-webpack-plugin with webpack dev server

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-jsons-webpack-plugin) to combine all my translation files in different folders into a single file in assets/i18n. But this happens only when I run ***webpack*** , but I want to work when I run my ***webpack dev server*** so that I can do live reload when I update my translate json files. This plugin writes to my dist folder only when I run ***webpack*** .How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest version of this plugin it should solve that issue.